# Question about open set of finite measure and Fubini's theorem.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to do the following exercise that appears in Stein and Shakarchi Real analysis.

Suppose $F$ is a closed set of $\mathbb R$ such that its complement has finite measure. Let $\delta(x)$ denote the distance from $F$ to $x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, prove that if $$I(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy,$$
then $I(x)<\infty$ for almost every $x\in F$. So the book hints to examine $\int_F I(x)dx$, so I guess you need to use Fubini's theorem to show $\int_F I(x)dx<\infty$, but I simply don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
I(x) = \int_{F^c} \frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy
$$
and, with a view to use Fubini-Tonelli, we have to prove that
$$
\int_{F^c} \left (\int_F \frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dx\right ) dy < \infty
$$
However, for any $y \in F^c$, one has
$$
\int_F \frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dx \leq \int_{|x-y|\geq \delta(y)} \frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dx = 2\int_{\delta(y)}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2} = \frac{2}{\delta(y)}
$$
and so
$$
\int_{F^c} \left (\int_F \frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dx\right ) dy \leq \int_{F^c} \delta(y)\frac{2}{\delta(y)}dy = 2m(F^c) < \infty
$$
Now the conclusion follows from what you have already observed.